# Google Analytics Experiments Count Page Views to the Original Page?

Tags: google-analytics

I am thinking of doing quite a few tests with GA Content Experiments and wanted to know when doing the tests do the page views for both variations count to the original page or do they get split on the regular GA stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pageviews for both the variations will be counted to original page only.

After running the experiment you will be able to drill down the pageviews for both the variations by querying [Experiment ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=content_experiments&jump=ga_experimentid) and [Variation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=content_experiments&jump=ga_experimentvariant) as `dimensions` and [Pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pageviews) as `metric` to Google Analytics.